# blazor dotnet 6 ProtectedBrowserStorage

Tags: blazor-server-side

i want to use localstorage in my blazor server side app
my dotnet is six

but whene i want inject ProtectedBrowserStorage service ... blazor error

> nvalidOperationException: Cannot provide a value for property 'pr' on
> type 'BlazorApp1.Pages.Index'. There is no registered service of type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage.ProtectedBrowserStorage'.

this is my code :

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage
@inject ProtectedBrowserStorage pr

@page "/"
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
```

and [this is microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-6.0&pivots=server)

Answer (score 1):

i must use "ProtectedLocalStorage" Not "ProtectedBrowserStorage"